# Evaluate $\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{r=1}^{4}(\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{s=1}^{4}(\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{4}rst))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{r=1}^{4}(\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{s=1}^{4}(\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{4}rst))$

How should you approach a question like this?
Thankyou

Comment: Can you do the inner most one to start? What do you notice after doing that one?

Comment: "How should you approach" ? From inside out.

Comment: Hint: $\sum\limits_{m=1}^4\sum\limits_{n=1}^4\left(f(m)g(n)\right)=\left(\sum\limits_{m=1}^4f(m)\right)\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^4g(n)\right)$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Just carry out the calculation. Work from the inside out. For any given values of $r$ and $s$ you know that

$$\sum_{t=1}^4rst=rs\sum_{t=1}^4t=10rs\;,$$

so the original expression can be simplified to

$$\frac12\sum_{r=1}^4\left(\frac12\sum_{s=1}^4\left(\frac12\cdot10rs\right)\right)=\frac12\sum_{r=1}^4\left(\frac12\sum_{s=1}^45rs\right)=\frac12\sum_{r=1}^4\frac52\sum_{s=1}^4rs\;.$$

Now, for any fixed value of $s$, what is $\sum_{s=1}^4rs$ in terms of $r$?